# Accessing the number of Facebook followers with hybridauth

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hybridauth

I try to get somehow the number of Facebook followers using hybridauth. I am using the following code:

```
$hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );
$adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( "facebook" );
echo var_dump($adapter->api()->api('/me/subscribers'));
```

However, the output is:

```
array (size=2)
  'data' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'summary' => 
    array (size=1)
      'total_count' => int 0
```

I have a Facebook account created for development and I have a lot of friends already there (just like Stan Marsh in the South Park episode about Facebook). If, instead if '/me/subscribers' I try with '/me/friends' then I get a list of friends with a paging. I have tried to raise the number of my followers, I have created another (sigh) Facebook user and with that I have visited my page and have clicked on the Interest list of my profile. I have then tested my code again. Still 0 followers. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After connecting with facebook we have to run something like this:

```
private function getFacebookData($username) {
    try{
        $counter = $this->adapter->api()->api($username."/subscribers")["summary"]["total_count"];
        return "Number of followers is: ".$counter;

    }
    catch( Exception $e ){
        return( "<b>got an error!</b> " . $e->getMessage() ); 
    }
}
```